# Cannot generate any migrations for Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.4. Syntax error in bin/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

Whenever I try to create a migration, I get the following error. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

```
$ rails generate migration NewMigration
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval': /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/rails:19: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby 2.1.4/bin/rails:23: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
from /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow your bin/rails file got modified. Run `gem pristine -a` in the same rvm you were using before. This rebuilds / reinstalls all your gem files.